# ¿Como puedo hacer que se genere 10 numeros aleatoriamente en pseint?

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Lo que quiero hacer es que tengo 10 datos 20, 30, 40, 50,... etc. y que se genere 20, 30, 40, 50, tipo 50,20,40,30 pero con los mismos datos no que me genere otros datos tengo este código

```
elazar=AZAR(num[10])
   Escribir elazar
   

pero me genera numero que no tengo. 31, 41 y así
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un arreglo de 10 elementos, para obtener un elemento al azar de ese arreglo debes:

1. Generar un número aleatorio en el rango de 1 - 10.
2. Extraer el elemento en el índice generado aleatorio.

Por ejemplo, dado un arreglo de 10 elementos `num[10]`. Para imprimir un elemento al azar del arreglo simplemente usas:

```
i = azar(10) + 1
Imprimir num[i]
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de un programa que imprime 10 elementos al azar de un arreglo:

```
Algoritmo imprimir_10_elementos_aleatorios_del_arreglo
    Dimension num[10]
    Para n <- 1 Hasta 10 Con Paso 1 paso Hacer
        num[n]<- n*10 
    Fin Para
    
    
    Para n <- 1 Hasta 10 Con Paso 1 paso Hacer
        i = azar(10) + 1
        Imprimir num[i]
    Fin Para
FinAlgoritmo
```